# DNS resolution not working as expected with CodeArtifact when using Wireguard

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, wireguard

I have the following situation when my VPN (Wireguard) is on and I try to access AWS CodeArtifact.

My VPN setup for Wireguard is the following:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <private_key>
Address = <my_wireguard_ip>
DNS = 169.254.169.253

[Peer]
PublicKey = <public_key>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/20, 169.254.169.253/32
Endpoint = <ip_endpoint>:<port>
```

As you can see, I use the DNS server at 169.254.169.253 to resolve internal hostnames in my VPC (10.0.0.0/20). For example, I have an internal load balancer hostname that resolves perfectly fine when the VPN is on:

```
nslookup ***.elb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Server:         169.254.169.253
Address:        169.254.169.253#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ***.elb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 10.0.1.164
Name:   ***.elb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 10.0.2.160
```

The problem happens when I try to access a CodeArtifact domain in the same region as where the Wireguard VPN instance is located:

```
$ aws codeartifact list-domains --region eu-central-1
Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/domains"
```

After some time it simply times out. Changing region works fine:

```
$ aws codeartifact list-domains --region us-east-1                                                                          
{
    "domains": []
}
```

Digging a bit more, I see that my domain CodeArtifact hostname in the `eu-central-1` regions are not being resolved:

```
$ nslookup my_codeartifact_domain-12345678.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Server:         169.254.169.253
Address:        169.254.169.253#53

** server can't find my_codeartifact_domain-12345678.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com: NXDOMAIN
```

However, the following gets resolved:

```
$ nslookup codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com                                                                          
Server:         169.254.169.253
Address:        169.254.169.253#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 10.0.4.94
```

If I change the DNS server, it resolves properly to public IPs:

```
$ nslookup my_codeartifact_domain-12345678.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com 8.8.8.8                                         
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   my_codeartifact_domain-12345678.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Address: <public_ip_1>
Name:   my_codeartifact_domain-12345678.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Address: <public_ip_2>
Name:   my_codeartifact_domain-12345678.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Address: <public_ip_3>
```

My assumption here is that the DNS server is trying to resolve internally the subdomains  `.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` and since my CodeArtifact domain is publicly available, it fails.

If I remove the DNS attribute (`DNS = 169.254.169.253`) from my wireguard configuration, it works perfectly fine.

My questions are:

1. Is my assumption correct? I don't really get why the domain CodeArtifact does not get resolved but `codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` instead does.
2. How can I successfully access CodeArtifact when the DNS is set up in the Wireguard configuration and the VPN is on? I need the DNS attribute to be in my Wireguard config as I have some internal hostnames in my VPC that need to be resolved.